# How to prove or disprove this algebraic inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, radicals, muirhead-inequality

How to prove or disprove the inequality (from math folklore)

> $$\sqrt{22(a^2+b^2+c^2)+5(ab+ac+bc)}\geq\sqrt{4a^2+ab+4b^2}+\sqrt{4b^2+bc+4c^2}+\sqrt{4c^2+ca+4a^2}$$
>   for nonnegative $a, b,$ and $c$?

My attempt :

> Squaring , we get  $$ 8\,{a}^{2}+ab+8\,{b}^{2}+2\,\sqrt {4\,{a}^{2}+ab+4\,{b}^{2}}\sqrt {4\,
> {b}^{2}+bc+4\,{c}^{2}}+2\,\sqrt {4\,{a}^{2}+ab+4\,{b}^{2}}\sqrt {4\,{a
> }^{2}+ac+4\,{c}^{2}}+bc+8\,{c}^{2}+2\,\sqrt {4\,{b}^{2}+bc+4\,{c}^{2}}
> \sqrt {4\,{a}^{2}+ac+4\,{c}^{2}}+ac\leq 22\,{a}^{2}+5\,ab+5\,ac+22\,{b
> }^{2}+5\,bc+22\,{c}^{2}.$$

My googling and search in MSE bring nothing to solve it. Numerical calculations confirm that inequality.

Comment: @AlexR: Can you give an example of nonalgebraic inequality?

Comment: @MarkiyanHirnyk The inequality you linked works with cube roots. How should that help you with an inequality containing only square roots? A first try of you should be to square both sides of the equation.

Comment: @MarkiyanHirnyk Yes. If you insist:
$$\|\sin \|_{L^1(\mathbb T)} \le 4$$

Comment: @ AlexR : I find it rather a bound in the form of a numeric inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{4a^2+ab+4b^2}\right)^2\leq\sum\limits_{cyc}(3a+3b+c)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{4a^2+ab+4b^2}{3a+3b+c}$.

Thus, it remains to prove that $7(a+b+c)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{4a^2+ab+4b^2}{3a+3b+c}\leq\sum\limits_{cyc}(22a^2+5ab)$, which is

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(15a^5+49a^4b+49a^4c-64a^3b^2-64a^3c^2+31a^3bc-16a^2b^2c^2)\geq0$, which is

$15\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^5-a^4b-a^4c+a^3bc)+64\sum\limits_{sym}(a^4b-a^3b^2)+16\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3bc-a^2b^2c)\geq0$, 
which is true by Schur and Muirhead.

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg: Thank you for your interest to the question and your consructive feedback. Can you elaborate the last step, i. e. the use of [Schur and Muirhead](http://www.cbseacademics.in/sites/default/files/concepts/Classical%20Inequalities%20concepts.pdf)?

Comment: For non-negatives $a$, $b$ and $c$ the inequality $\sum_{cyc}(a^5-a^4b-a^4c+a^3bc)\geq0$ is Schur. We can

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg: Could you kindly explain that statement in detail?

Comment: Of course! Let $a\geq b\geq c$. Hence, $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^5-a^4b-a^4c+a^3bc)=\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3(a-b)(a-c)\geq a^3(a-b)(a-c)+b^3(b-a)(b-c)=(a-b)(a^3(a-c)-b^3(b-c))\geq0$. By the way, $\sum\limits_{sym}(a^4b-a^4c)=\sum\limits_{cyc}ab(a+b)(a-b)^2\geq0$ and $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3bc-a^2b^2c)=\frac{1}{2}abc\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0$.

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg: Still don't understand why $$  \sum\limits_{cyc}a^3(a-b)(a-c)\geq a^3(a-b)(a-c)+b^3(b-a)(b-c)$$ and the second one and the third one. BTW, I don't see any Schur here.

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg: I got $$ \sum\limits_{cyc}a^3(a-b)(a-c)\geq a^3(a-b)(a-c)+b^3(b-a)(b-c).$$ The third term $c^3(c-a)(c-b)$ is nonnegative as $a\geq b\geq c.$ I still don't understand $$\sum\limits_{sym}(a^4b-a^4c)=\sum\limits_{cyc}ab(a+b)(a-b)^2\geq0$$ and $$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3bc-a^2b^2c)=\frac{1}{2}abc\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq 0.$$ I think two small steps are better than one big step.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{sym}(a^4b-a^3b^2)=\sum_{cyc})a^4b+b^4a-a^3b^2-b^3a^2)=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b)ab$.  $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3bc-a^2b^2c)=abc\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=$ $\frac{1}{2}abc\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-2ab+b^2)=\frac{1}{2}abc\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2$.

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg: Can you explain how  you came to that complicated proof?